# Floating child items with parent window collapsing

Tags: css

If you have a parent window with display block. Any children within that element that are being floated will be displayed with the parent window "collapsed".

For example:

```html
 <div>
    <p style="float: left;">Stuff</p>
    <p style="float: right;">More stuff</p>
 </div>
```

Will render with both `<p>` outside of `<div>`. However, if you change `<div>` to display: inline-block... it will not "collapse". Why...what's going on behind the scenes here that I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 0):

As [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) says :

> The element is removed from the normal flow of the page

If you want your div element height considering your p elements, you should use something else than float property. You can use [Flexible Box Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) for instance